Add the option to auto-upvote a post on approval of a suggested-edit
When doing a suggested-edit, the goal is to improve a post to such a degree, so that there is a good question/answer in the end. Good posts should be reflected in the score.
Therefore, I propose that, similar to the additional option in the staging-ground, one could conditionally upvote a question on approval of a suggested-edit:

This would trigger adding an upvote on the reviewers choosing "Approve" or the "Approve and edit" options.

Why not just upvote the question manually?
Bad posts should not receive upvotes and:

No matter how good the suggest-edit is, there is no guarantee that the edit will be approved.
Depending on the popularity of the technology, reviews take from weeks, to sometimes, months.
There should be a correlation between edit and upvote that the original asker/answerer can see, so they hopefully learn what posts on SO are supposed to look like.


Why?  Just upvote it.  If the edit is good, it should be approved.

Can questions in the SG have suggested edits? (I honestly don't know.) I've never seen one when I've been in there.

@ThomA On SG you have the option to auto-upvote on the question being posted on main.

Yes, I know, but I'm not asking about the "Add an upvote when approved" feature; you mention when doing a suggested edit, I asked about suggested edits. So users with < 2k reputation can do suggested edits on posts in the SG and it goes to the Suggested edits queue?

Possibly related: Should we vote for the history of questions or answers?

@ThomA there are no suggested edits in SG; <2k users (with SG access) can edit posts in SG directly.

Ahh, I see, i misunderstood; you're using the SG as an example of where similar functionality exists, not as where this is occurring; I thought you meant you were doing suggested edits in the SG and couldn't choose to upvote it when it's approved at the same time. Apologies.

@RyanM This is specifically about suggested-edits. They are not always approved, no matter how good I think my edit is. Also reviewing takes a lot of time (especially if the post is about something niche) sometimes it took months. Why have an unjustified upvote on a bad post all that time?

Also, the asker perhaps sees the correlation between upvote and edit if they are at the same time. Which could lead to him understanding better what makes a good question/answer.

Ouch, I would not have guessed a delay of months (based on the length of the queue and rate of reviews).  Okay, that's a fair point, then.

If the post can be improved by other users, to the point it deserves an upvote, then the content of the original post also deserves an upvote. Or the other way around, if the post is so bad that it doesn't deserve an upvote without suggested edit, then I highly doubt that any suggested edit could improve the post to the point it would deserve an upvote.

@DalijaPrasnikar I can assure you it is possible. See this edit.

@A-Tech I disagree. That question does not deserve an upvote before nor after the edit. While it is better than many questions, there is no proper problem statement. It is just I need to do this, here is my code, please fix it. That is not a good question.

Ok then take this one. Remember however that 2 people will decide the differently on when and how to vote on a given post. Otherwise, all my posts would only have upvotes or downvotes. I saw and improved posts that I thought will be a useful question/answer, but the writer just didnt know SO etiquette, how to format, how to ask homework questions etc.

Eh I wouldn't upvote that even after your edit, @A-Tech ; "It fails" is no more helpful a description of the problem than the OP's "It does not work".

As far as I'm aware, the system already notifies you when your edit is approved. If you're invested enough in a question that you think your edit makes the difference between it being upvote-worthy or not, you should be able to go back and upvote it manually.
Since, as you say, reviews can take months, this also allows for the fact that you might change your mind in the interim.

And it is never just the one edit too. There can be multiple... and also rollbacks. If the goal is to not have an unjust upvote on the post, then do not upvote until the editing phase has wound down. The checkbox is not the correct implementation towards that goal.

There is no explicit notification for edit approval. You do get 2 rep for it, which might trigger the rep counter notification showing you +2. That is not guaranteed. The "rep balloon" only shows up if the total rep you got since you last opened the achievements counter is positive. So, if you had, say, -5 rep for any reason, then a +2, you won't see the green balloon with +2 because your total is still -3. If then a post of yours gets an upvote, that goes to a total of +7. And that's what you'd see in the rep popup.

Relevant meta post - Tell users when their edits are rejected
